# preg_match_all loop for each match, verify if empty to set null values to insert in table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, regex, preg-match-all

I have 10 lines to extract from file text with other lines, some are empty but exist, others don't exist but I have to insert them anyway, with regex can split text by 10 group, I use preg_match_all to match group and generate a array with matches, but if the lines not exist not matched, I want insert values group to insert in mysql table and if the value is empty set a NULL.

I just need them only values, but first verify if keys exist and add missing keys and NULL values for this.

if the value is empty set NULL, if the group not exist in text file add a values to set a NULL to insert in table mysql.

**please see UPDATE QUESTION**

i should use array_push, array_key_exists or in the regex assign a name by each group?

and the last, how to loop each matches? with preg_match_all generate only one array with full match, but my table mysql only 10 columns one for each group regex.

**UPDATE QUESTION: I rephrased the post 11/24/21 01.00**

for example full data are 10 lines

```
/*
First Name         :NameAAAAAA
LINE TO EXCLUDE    : this line is to exclude     
Last Name          :LastAAAAAA
LINE TO EXCLUDE    : this line is to exclude
Gender = (F/M)     :
ANOTHER LINE TO EXCLUDE : this line is to exclude                             
        TEST INFO 1      :TI1AAAAAA
        ANOTHER LINE TO EXCLUDE  : this line is to exclude             
        TEST INFO 2      :       
        TEST INFO 3      :TI3AAAAAA
First Name         :NameBBBBBB
LINE TO EXCLUDE    : this line is to exclude     
Last Name          :LastBBBBBB
LINE TO EXCLUDE    : this line is to exclude
Gender = (F/M)     :
First Name         :NameCCCCCC
LINE TO EXCLUDE    : this line is to exclude     
Last Name          :LastCCCCCC
LINE TO EXCLUDE    : this line is to exclude
Gender = (F/M)     :M
ANOTHER LINE TO EXCLUDE : this line is to exclude                             
        TEST INFO 1      :
        ANOTHER LINE TO EXCLUDE  : this line is to exclude             
        TEST INFO 2      :TI2CCCCCC       
        TEST INFO 3      :
*/
```

to extract only lines (6 lines) with regex:

https://regex101.com/r/hWzvOr/1

```
/.*(?:First Name).*|.*(?:Last Name).*|.*(?:Gender = \(F\/M\)).*|.*(?:TEST INFO 1).*|.*(?:TEST INFO 2).*|.*(?:TEST INFO 3).*/g
```

following string after extract with regex pattern: it's possibile founds not exist lines (see TEST INFO 1-2-3 in group NameBBBBBB)

```
$str = '
First Name         :NameAAAAAA    
Last Name          :LastAAAAAA                 
Gender = (F/M)     :                            
        TEST INFO 1   :TI1AAAAAA     
        TEST INFO 2   :       
        TEST INFO 3   :TI3AAAAAA  
First Name         :NameBBBBBB   
Last Name          :LastBBBBBB                 
Gender = (F/M)     :                                                                                 
First Name         :NameCCCCCC   
Last Name          :LastCCCCCC                 
Gender = (F/M)     :M                            
        TEST INFO 1   :     
        TEST INFO 2   :TI2CCCCCC       
        TEST INFO 3   : 
';
```

if no exist (no match) create key by dynamic and value set to NULL, if value is empty set to NULL.

must generate, (see TEST INFO 1-2-3 in group NameBBBBBB)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => First Name         :NameAAAAAA    
            [1] => Last Name          :LastAAAAAA                 
            [2] => Gender = (F/M)     :                            
            [3] =>         TEST INFO 1   :TI1AAAAAA     
            [4] =>         TEST INFO 2   :       
            [5] =>         TEST INFO 3   :TI3AAAAAA 
            [6] => First Name         :NameBBBBBB    
            [7] => Last Name          :LastBBBBBB                 
            [8] => Gender = (F/M)     : 
            [9] =>         TEST INFO 1   :                        
            [10] =>        TEST INFO 2   :
            [11] =>        TEST INFO 3   :                             
            [12] => First Name         :NameCCCCCC    
            [13] => Last Name          :LastCCCCCC                 
            [14] => Gender = (F/M)     : M                           
            [15] =>         TEST INFO 1   :                        
            [16] =>         TEST INFO 2   :TI2CCCCCC
            [17] =>         TEST INFO 3   :                                          
        )

)
```

how to create keys if not match in regex? the loop generate one array with all data, but i insert each loop 6 lines values in one table with 6 columns into mysql?

thanks in advance.

Regards.

Italo.

Comment: I played with it and [came up **with this** (demo)](https://tio.run/##bVFha4MwEP2eX3FjQrTrtHYfBjpbQpUhiJXVdh@sLVLSKbNOYhyU0d/uoutWyjxCuNy99@54KdOyaZ6mZVoiJDEKFmBts04HcrQx1kV8N1XEw2gL6qDLJe2ATYGtOGvBCLogQeC5MxK6cx9cG/6HQdq4FWekj/Rz8UxehCRcLiCwAse3Xf9ZIxaZhe7KuZB7FH/ZK@K59n04B5uETh/OeNT18YPez56/@s5L/8pn9hVcVdVrldaLbC@XjL5tDwnfpdskz2Xh5BBai8TdVWmlTEYKfAkZ0auEcxF@p8cKgzX5g0R6PAT8meQ1/WkkjCVHIVvK@7rY8eyjkCUqVIBRXrMCJHpjYQxTkYg9sb/0PGzC6TI0GsdKbKITQpoGAcsKDjylQAueib/uQEKrqnOOyra7Ze3qlWKipvkG). Maybe it's helpful.

Comment: thanks for answer, I rephrased the post, the data have only same lines extract fromlines  match regex, not for all data. Please see my update question in post. thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Build an array with all needed keys and values set to null:

```php
$columns = [
    'APPLICATION ID',
    'STATUS P=PENDING/A=ACTIVE',
    /*...*/
    'RUN CYCLE DESCRIPTION'
];

$keys = array_fill_keys($columns, null);
```

2. Build a pattern to extract keys and values present in your string. To do that, it's totally useless to put all the needed keys in your pattern, you just need to use capture groups (named here) to isolate keys from values for each match (note that the *value* group is optional):

```php
$pat = '~^ \h*+ (?<key> [^:\n]* [^:\s] ) \h* : (?<value> \S+ (?:\h+\S+)* )? ~xm';
```

3. Use `preg_match_all` with the `PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL` flag: when the optional *value* group isn't matched, the returned value is `null` instead of an empty string.
   With the `preg_match_all` match results, build an associative array with the `$matches['key']` and `$matches['value']` subarrays (note that this one has the same keys than the array `$keys` except that eventually some keys are missing).
   Then all you have to do is to merge the `$keys` array with this new array to obtain an associative array with the key/value pairs you are interested by.

```php
if ( preg_match_all($pat, $yourstring, $matches, PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL) ) {
    $result = array_combine($matches['key'], $matches['value']);
    // $result = array_intersect_key($result, $keys); // if you need to exclude some key/value pairs from the string
    $result = array_merge($keys, $result);
}
```

1,2,3 Aquafresh® 3

Comment: thanks for answer, I rephrased the post, the data have only same lines extract from lines match regex, not for all data. In your step 3) in $result array only have a last loop and the info is merge with data from the before loop if the lines not exist. Please see my update question in post. thanks again.

Comment: @italo_pm: If you have lines to exclude, it's not a problem, add `$result = array_intersect_key($result, $keys);` before the `array_merge` line.

Comment: @italo_pm: split your string before applying the script, and process a block at once.

Comment: thanks Casimir for answer, with array_intersect_key exclude lines works fine but the last array $result have only last reult loop and not all lines loop, how to save all lines loop?  ` 
    $result = array_combine($matches['key'], $matches['value']);
    $result = array_intersect_key($result, $keys);
    $result = array_merge($keys, $result);
 print_r( $result, true )  Array
(
    [First Name] => NameCCCCCC
    [Last Name] => LastCCCCCC
    [Gender = (F/M)] => M
    [TEST INFO 1] => 
    [TEST INFO 2] => TI2CCCCCC
    [TEST INFO 3] => 
)` thanks again.

Comment: @italo_pm: store the result for each block: https://3v4l.org/5GvSS (or send them to the database one a time inside the loop).

Answer (score 1):

I would process this in multiple steps:

```
$str = '
      APPLICATION ID                   :AAAAA#AA#0101       
      STATUS P=PENDING/A=ACTIVE        :A                    
      VALID-TO DATE                    :711231               
      APPLICATION TYPE (A/G)           :A                    
      DESCRIPTIVE TEXT                 :DESC folder AAAAA    
      OWNER ID                         :               
      RANDOM INFO                      :                     
            PERIOD OR RUN CYCLE GROUP NAME   :QAZ123XX        
            RUN CYCLE VALID-FROM             :711230          
            RUN CYCLE VALID-TO               :711231          
            RUN CYCLE DESCRIPTION            :MANUAL ORDER    
            RUN RANDOM IFO                   :                
      APPLICATION ID                   :BBBBB#BB#0101       
      STATUS P=PENDING/A=ACTIVE        :A                    
      VALID-TO DATE                    :711231               
      APPLICATION TYPE (A/G)           :A                    
      DESCRIPTIVE TEXT                 :                     
      OWNER ID                         :OWNER1               
      RANDOM INFO                      :                     
';
```

plus

```
$groups = explode('APPLICATION ID', $str);
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    echo "----\n";
    $hash = [];
    if (empty($group)) continue;
    $group = 'APPLICATION ID' . $group;
    $lines = preg_split("/\n/", $group);
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        $kv = explode(':', $line);
       if (count($kv) == 2 && trim($kv[1]) != '')
            $hash[trim($kv[0])] = trim($kv[1]);
    }
    print_r($hash);

    // TODO:  Build an INSERT with just the values in $hash
    // Meanwhile, each column should be `DEFAULT NULL`.
}
```

Yields:

```
----
Array
(
)
----
Array
(
    [APPLICATION ID] => AAAAA#AA#0101
    [STATUS P=PENDING/A=ACTIVE] => A
    [VALID-TO DATE] => 711231
    [APPLICATION TYPE (A/G)] => A
    [DESCRIPTIVE TEXT] => DESC folder AAAAA
    [PERIOD OR RUN CYCLE GROUP NAME] => QAZ123XX
    [RUN CYCLE VALID-FROM] => 711230
    [RUN CYCLE VALID-TO] => 711231
    [RUN CYCLE DESCRIPTION] => MANUAL ORDER
)
----
Array
(
    [APPLICATION ID] => BBBBB#BB#0101
    [STATUS P=PENDING/A=ACTIVE] => A
    [VALID-TO DATE] => 711231
    [APPLICATION TYPE (A/G)] => A
    [OWNER ID] => OWNER1
)
```

Another tip:  `NULLIF(?, '')`

Comment: thanks for answer, in the Yields section, in the first array missing keys OWNER ID                         :  with empty values,  in the second array should have array keys and the values empty  (not exist)  [DESCRIPTIVE TEXT] [PERIOD OR RUN CYCLE GROUP NAME] =>     [RUN CYCLE VALID-FROM] =>     [RUN CYCLE VALID-TO] =>     [RUN CYCLE DESCRIPTION] => , i read in your answer that it would be missing to do that. Please see my update question in post. thanks again.